# Apache upgrade in CentOS 7

Tags: apache, centos7

This is my current version of Apache:

```
httpd -V

Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Apr 24 2019 13:45:48
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:24
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
threaded:       no
forked:         yes (variable process count)
```

I am using CentOS 7; when I try to update Apache, it says there are no upgrades. I know the latest version is `2.4.39`: mine is `2.4.6`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at RHEL's [security backports page](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting). It explains the process RH uses to update version numbers. Basically, even though your `httpd -V` says `2.4.6`, RH may have updated the features and fixed issues from the CVE without updating the version number. Run `rpm -q --changelog httpd | grep CVE-yyyy-nnnn`, filling in `yyyy-nnnn` with a recent timestamp from the [CVE list](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=apache%202.4.6), and see if your version has received those updates.

Alternatively, you may not have the latest CentOS version, which may not have the updated list of software. Run `yum update` to be sure you have the latest version.

Comment: Although this is factually correct, but OP might not be looking to upgrade because of security reasons. It would be helpful to mention that you can install newer versions in parallel to the one CentOS ships with.